# Is there an inverse Lamperti transformation for diffusions?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

The Lamperti transformation is commonly used to transform SDEs with state dependent coefficients into SDEs with constant diffusion.

For multidimensional processes there are some conditions on the drift that have to be valid before applying the transformation (e.g., drift should be the gradient of  potential).

If we consider a general multidimensional SDE with constant drift
$$ dX_t = f(X_t) dt + \sigma dW_t, $$

can we get the other way around, i.e., can we convert it to a driftless SDE with state dependent coefficient?
I.e., obtain an equation like this $$dY_t = \sigma(Y_t) dW_t$$,

or this $$dY_t =g(Y_t) dt+ \sigma(Y_t) dW_t$$. (here $g()$ shall conform to the conditions of the Lamperti transform).

If yes, what are the conditions for this?

Comment: Uh, isn’t this doable by Girsanov’s theorem?

Comment: @NateRiver No the Girsanov requires the diffusion coefficient to remain unchanged.  Here I want to change to the diffusion.

Comment: can you add more details? The Girsanov's applies to coefficients that depends on both X,t $$ dX_t=\mu(X_t,t)dt+\sigma(X_t,t)dW_t, dY_t=(\mu(Y_t,t)+\nu(Y_t,t))dt+\sigma(Y_t,t)dW_t$$.  See wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girsanov_theorem#Application_to_Langevin_Equations

Comment: @ThomasKojar the two SDEs you mention have the same diffusion function. I would like to transform from $dX_t = f(X_t) dt + \sigma dW_t$ to $dY_t = \sigma(Y_t) dW_t$, i.e., I want to change the diffusion coefficient, if possible.

Comment: do you mean different sigma? see here for mutually singular example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79875/laws-of-b-t-t-in-0-t-and-2b-t-t-in-0-t-singular

Comment: here too: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51090/change-of-time-or-change-of-measure

Comment: introducing state dependence to sigma only makes it more complicated. So Girsanov's gives you a simpler answer of non-dependence.

Comment: @ThomasKojar Yes I know that it get more complicated, I want it as a theoretical result, to know that such a transformation is possible and under which conditions.

Comment: but it is not true. When you change the volatility, you change the quadratic function and they become mutually singular.

Comment: @ThomasKojar Then how does the forward Lamperti transform work? There you change a state dependent diffusion into a constant diffusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Girsanov's applies to state dependent states. So it actually gives simpler answer if initially the volatility didn't depend on the state.

But for changing to a different volatility, the result is false because it changes the quadratic function and thus creates a mutually singular process, see here:

[Change of time or change of measure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51090/change-of-time-or-change-of-measure)

where they consider the event $A=\{\omega:[\omega]_T=a\sigma^2T\}  $ which is $1$ for one process and $0$ for the other.

Now in particular for the Lamperti transform. Following the results 2.1.5/2.1.6 from ["The Lamperti Transform"](https://repository.tudelft.nl/islandora/object/uuid%3A948769c8-49e5-4175-9990-76b3235f7a25) by de Boer,

first using Ito to compute for general map $\psi$.
[image]

then for this specific $\psi$ below, they turn the volatility coefficient to be one.

[image]

So since this mapping is 1-1 we can reverse the above procedure: $\psi$ is invertible and so starting from concrete $Z_{t}$, we can define $X_{t}:=\psi^{-1}(Z_{t})$. This will give the state-dependent diffusion from 2.1.5.

Comment: When you employ a Lamperti transform what property of the stochastic process do you assume that remains the same?
https://www.clarusft.com/lamperti-transform/

Comment: See here
https://mathoverflow.net/a/69299/483817

Comment: in this note, they have a nice explanation too: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjixpn5oMD7AhXukokEHU-1D7EQFnoECBAQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Frepository.tudelft.nl%2Fislandora%2Fobject%2Fuuid%3A948769c8-49e5-4175-9990-76b3235f7a25%2Fdatastream%2FOBJ%2Fdownload%23%3A~%3Atext%3DThe%2520Lamperti%2520transform%2520is%2520a%2Csystem%2520of%2520stochastic%2520differential%2520equations.&usg=AOvVaw16RQTrhvtTMMKhgO7UaOlM

Comment: so since that mapping psi is 1-1 in Theorem 2.1.6, you could try to consider the inverse $X_t=\psi^{-1}(Z_{t})$ i.e. starting from some concrete Zt and then obtaining Xt, but then you will naturally pick up a drift term.